# tree map with several keys and range search support

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, treemap, database-indexes

I need an efficient data structure which holds mapping of pairs to values

```
(x,y) => v
```

and allows to find key-value pairs matching 2d range expression:

```
x1 < x < x2 && y1 < y < y2
```

faster then full search. I have some solution, though it is heavy to implement. Is there any standard algorithm/approach for such task? I believe DB developers had to solve this problem while addressing compound indexes problem.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far. Also what data types are x, y, and z?

Comment: can you also provide sample data of what you wish to accomplish

Comment: The kD tree is your friend. http://geom-java.sourceforge.net/demos/drawRangeKDTreeDemo.html

Comment: Dear @YvesDaoust , if you write detailed answer about kD tree, i'll accept it, thanx you!

Comment: kD trees are a well-documented data structure and I don't want to add my own description. I think there's more valuable information in my answer.

Comment: @stiv: thanks. Would be nice if you tell us if you find a solution that suits you in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a very simple solution, try this:

- keep the keys sorted on x;
- given a query range, find the first point in the x range by dichotomy;
- loop on x until the end of the x-range and test on y.

Assuming that your keys are uniformly spread, if the x-range occupies a fraction Fx of the whole domain, the speedup compared to exhaustive search is 1/Fx (not 1/Fx.Fy, unfortunately).

Even though the gain may look insignificant, it is worth to implement it to compare it against exhaustive search and any more sophisticated method that you could try.

---

Another easy solution is by *gridding*, i.e. storing the points in linked lists associated to every grid cell. Then the search can be limited to the cells that overlap the range.

You will need to find a good compromise on the cell size; cells much larger than the typical size of the ranges are inefficient; but cells so small that most of them are empty are also inefficient.

The *quad-tree* data structure can be seen as an adaptive version of gridding.